# When writing a new major mode, should it add itself to auto-mode-alist?

Tags: major-mode, elisp-conventions

I am defining a new major mode, `foo-mode`, which is closely and only associated with `.foo` files. Should `foo-mode.el` fiddle with `auto-mode-alist` to add this association, or is that the user's responsibility?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that if your library is intended to be installed via package.el (or similar) and you have included an autoload cookie for `foo-mode`, and you choose to implement the `auto-mode-alist` manipulation, then you will want to use an autoload cookie for that as well.  Otherwise the user would need to either load your library before visiting a `*.foo` file, or else write their own `auto-mode-alist` entry.

I don't think there's a hard and fast rule about this.  I *suspect* that now that ELPA is pretty standard, it's more common for packages to update `auto-mode-alist` automatically, to streamline the installation process.  I'd say just use your own judgement, and be sure to still provide equivalent manual installation instructions in your commentary.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say *yes*. If the user has installed `foo-mode`, they have installed it to use with `.foo` files. When I run `emacs -Q`, there are 184 items in the list (including `.org`, `.java`, `.xml`, `.letter`, and more, so it's not kept too small.